# Does IE 10 support event.target?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>
<html>
<body>
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="Code libraries">Code libraries</a></li>
    <li><a href="Web sites">Web sites</a></li>
    <li><a href="Archives">Archives</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var navigation = document.getElementById("navigation");
    navigation.onclick = function (evt) {
        var event = evt || window.event;
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var text = "Link's text: " + target.innerHTML;
        alert(text);
    }
};
</script>
```

Question:

If I changed :

```
var event = evt || window.event;
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
```

to

```
var event = evt;
var target = event.target;
```

It still works in IE(I am using IE 10), Does this mean: IE10 also support `event.target`, and in the future I do not need to use this kind of code: `var target = event.target || event.srcElement;`?

Comment: Next time, you might just want to check Microsoft's documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974946(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: [IE9 and above versions of this browser are not available for Windows XP users](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/system-requirements), so better keep the backward compatibility for IE8/7 fans untouched for at least few next years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.target` is already available in IE9+. If you need to support IE6-8, then `event.srcElement` needs to be used.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target
- http://help.dottoro.com/ljprbjte.php